# FF 3.6 and jQuery 1.7 and removeEventListener()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an issue with FireFox 3.6 not liking me calling a non-jQuery function within jQuery (v1.7.2).

Cut down version of my code:

```
function doInitialiseForm( theField ) {
  /* loop through a few fields and set the appropriate attributes & class */
  nX = parseInt( theField ) ;
  var inputElement = '' ;
  for ( i=(nX + 1); i <= 10 ; i++ )
  {
    $('#acBox' + i).addClass('pHide') ;  
    /* toggle the required attribute/class on the input boxes - for HTML5 input validation to behave correctly ... */
    inputElement =  document.getElementById('acBoxName_' + i ) ;
    inputElement.removeAttribute('required');
    $( inputElement ).removeClass( 'required' )
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  if ( isBookingPage == '1' )
  {
      doInitialiseForm( document.getElementById('AttendingCount') ) ;  
  }
});
```

The error FireFox is reporting:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments"  nsresult: "0x80570001   (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)"  location: "JS frame :: http//development_server/Booking/js/script.js :: doInitialiseForm:: line 65"  data: no]
```

It seems to be related to FF expecting a third parameter to the `removeEventListener()` thingy, which is optional. But, I'm not directly using `removeEventListener()`.

What additional code would I need implement in order to get the above code to work in the older version of FireFox?

Comment: Firefox 3.6 Support ended On April 24, 2012, you are still supporting it?

Comment: Why mix DOM and jQuery? `$('#acBoxName_' + i ).removeAttr('required').removeClass( 'required' );`

Comment: parseInt on a DOM object, how does that work?

Comment: @epascarello - 24th April really isn't that long ago you know. I know Mozilla have gone nuts with their version numbers in the meanwhile, but there are still people using 3.6. And it's not as if FF3.6 is really that bad a browser compared with some others that are still in use. In any case, jQuery still supports it, so there shouldn't be problems; the question is a valid one.

Comment: I have mixed DOM and jQuery because jQuery's removeAttr() wasn't working as expected - it didn't actually remove the attribute from the input field. (i.e. <input type="text" required> to <input type="text">). Setting a value to the "required" attribute wouldn't work when using the jQuery validator plugin)

Comment: FF 3.6 has around a [1.5% share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201206-201206-bar) worldwide last month. Also your parseInt line still makes no sense. Do you have a typo there?

Comment: @epascarello the parseInt is required due to theField being a Select input box. 

Just realised I've written the "nX = parseInt( theField )" line incorrectly - should read: "nX = parseInt( theField.value )" - that's how it is currently written in my code. 

I have deliberately omitted some code from the doInitialiseForm() function as it wasn't relevant to the issue I'm having. I have a piece of code adding 1 to the theField.value ... but Javascript treated theField.value as string instead of a number, hence the parseInt() call.  

Re FF version <4, our web-server is recording 5%.

Answer (score 0):

Issue now resolved.

Part of the omitted code from the function doInitialiseForm() was calling setAttribute() and I didn't include the second parameter.

i.e. originally written as

```
inputElement.setAttribute('required');
```

when it should be

```
inputElement.setAttribute('required','');
```